# Pipeline Logging in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have been developing ADF pipelines and using SQL Server tables to log at each stage of the pipeline run.

Now that the organisation has decided to move away from SQL Server and rely only on the ADF (Data being outputted into excel / csv files - so we dont need SQL Server).

I am wondering how can i log each step and the output including all the errors in the ADF itself ?

and can we customise the errors logged for messaging purposes ?

Also My pipelines were previously using the SQL Tables to check if the pipeline is already running (by checking values in tables) and do not start the pipeline if that is the case, if we move away from SQL server, is there a way we can achieve these in ADF ?

Is it something configurable in ADF ?

I have tried to google it, but couldn't find a satisfactory solution.
Any help please?

Answer (score 0):

What are your source and sink in case of ADF ?
Is it blob location?
You can use a file to read and write your logs based on custom logics, my blog can help :
https://datasharkx.wordpress.com/2021/08/19/error-logging-and-the-art-of-avoiding-redundant-activities-in-azure-data-factory/

Else you can configure diagnostic settings in ADF :https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/monitor-configure-diagnostics

for your logs to get into Log Analytics or blob location automatically

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is just to use log analytics, verbose logs there should be enough for anything that you might need. It is indeed a good idea to move away from legacy applications.

You should be able to customize the logging level.

To check for values you normally use Lookup inside an if statement, and you can connect it to an ExecutePipeline activity which starts based on a True or False condition.

Answer (score 0):

From that list of requirements it sounds like you need a different low or no-cost database.  Yes there is probably a technical workaround using multiple various Azure tools but it's arguable if it's worth doing.

Azure Cosmos DB (NoSQL) is free to a certain point- 1,000 RU/s and 25 GB of storage for free for the lifetime of the account.

If you want a heavily discounted relational SQL Server db, you can plan your pipeline runs accordingly and use Azure SQL Server Database Server-less; which you only pay storage costs when it's deactivated.  I think the best part of this one is it abstracts the annual SQL Server licensing fees and you don't pay for a VM on top.  Can easily have this one for $20-$50 month with low usage and it's still Enterprise.